# Tabulator headerMenu help needed

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using this great library [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/), all works fine but I would like to make my code more efficient so I want make one headerMenu function for set desired value to each column in table.
Now I am using separate function for each column and it is working fine but there are 8 routines for each field...

I am trying to do this in one function like this:

```
var headerMenu= [{                            
    label:"Set All in column to ON",
    action:function(e, column){
        var columnField = column.getField();
        var rows = userTable.getRows(); 
        console.log( columnField );             // already prints desired column field f.e. sw4
        userTable.blockRedraw();                                                               
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            row.update({columnField :true});    // nothing happens                                                            
        }); 
        userTable.restoreRedraw();                                                             
    }
},
{
    label:"Set All in column to OFF",
    action:function(e, column){
        var columnField = column.getField();
        var rows = userTable.getRows(); 
        console.log( columnField );
        userTable.blockRedraw();                                                               
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            row.update({columnField :false});                                                            
        }); 
        userTable.restoreRedraw();                                                            
    }
}]
// my table setup
columns:[
        { title:'ID', field:'id', width:50 },
        { title:'DIP NAME', field:'name', headerFilter:'input', editor:'input', hozAlign:'center' },
        { title:' DIP SWITCHES', hozAlign:'center',
            columns:[               
                { title:'SW1', field:'sw1',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu },
                { title:'SW2', field:'sw2',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu },
                { title:'SW3', field:'sw3',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu },
                { title:'SW4', field:'sw4',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu },
                { title:'SW5', field:'sw5',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu },
                { title:'SW6', field:'sw6',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu },
                { title:'SW7', field:'sw7',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu },
                { title:'SW8', field:'sw8',  width:30, hozAlign:'center', editor:true, formatter:'tickCross', headerVertical:true, headerFilter:'tickCross',  headerFilterParams:{"tristate":true}, headerSort:false, headerMenu:headerMenu }
            ],
        }
],
 //
```

but nothing happens in table even console prints real field name, no error.

But when I change columnField with desired field name for example:

```
...
row.update({sw1 :false});
...
```

function works fine and all those fields are changend OK.

Can someone help what I am doing wrong?

I am still beginner and I cant help myself...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row.update({columnField : false});`

This is not evaluating the variable the way you think it should. Actually you are setting a property named "columnField" instead of using the value of the `columnField` variable.

You need to use [Computed Property Names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript). Wrap your variable in [brackets] like this:

`row.update({ [columnField] : false});`

Comment: Thank you so much, its works!I will study link you post.Thank you.